# "Stronger" form of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, divergent-series, arithmetic-progressions, distribution-of-primes

Let $a$ and $q$ be two relatively prime positive integers. If I know that
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{+}}\sum_{p\equiv a \bmod q}\frac{1}{p^s}=+\infty,$$
then it is clear that it tells me that there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression $\{a+kq:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. I wonder if there is an easy way to deduce that actually

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{\substack{p\leq x\\p\equiv a \bmod q}}\frac{1}{p}=+\infty.$$

My problem is that if I assume by contradiction that $\sum_{p\equiv a \bmod q}\frac{1}{p}$ converges, then nothing tells me that it should be equal to $\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{+}}\sum_{p\equiv a \bmod q}\frac{1}{p^s}$, or at least nothing that I know. How can this be proven?

Comment: Since all the terms are nonnegative, by Tonelli's theorem you can evaluate $$\lim_{s\to1+} \lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{\substack{p\le x \\ p\equiv a\pmod q}} \frac1{p^s}$$ by doing either limit first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes that makes sense. We simply use the fact that $\sum_{\substack{p\leq x \\ p\equiv a\pmod q}} \frac1{p^s}$ is increasing in each variable $s$ and $x$ separately as $x$ increases and as $s\rightarrow 1^{+}$, right?

Comment: note that $\sum_{\substack{p\leq x\\p\equiv a \bmod q}}\frac{1}{p}$ is a sum on various character sums for which the principal character sum goes to infinity, while the complex character ($\chi \ne \bar \chi$) sums are finite by conjugation, so regardless of how you approach this, you still need to show that the real non-principal character sums are finite and do not go to minus infinity